# How to get a Facebook user's current country?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The Facebook Graph API provides a user's [current location](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) in two formats: name and ID. ID can be something like *104022926303756*. Name can be something like *Palo Alto, California* or *Beijing, China*. From these two fields, how do I extract the country? All American locations are in the form `[City], [State]` whereas all non-American locations are in the form `[City], [Country]`. Can I code something less hacky than:

```
$states = array(
 'Alabama'
 'Alaska',
 'Arizona',
 // ...
);

$country = 'USA';
if (!in_array($locationName, $states)) {
    preg_match('#, ([a-z]+$)#i', $locationName, $match);
    $country = $match[1];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using this: [http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20current_location%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%3Dme()](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20current_location%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%3Dme%28%29)

?

As you can see, using FQL on user table, the JSON you'll receive is something like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "current_location": {
        "city": "Turin", 
        "state": "Piemonte", 
        "country": "Italy", 
        "zip": "", 
        "id": 115351801811432, 
        "name": "Turin, Italy"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

There you have the field country, much more readable :-)

**EDIT:** <strike>The link is broken because brakets are missing at the end of query,</strike> anyway the FQL query is:

```
SELECT current_location FROM user WHERE uid=me()
```

"me()" can be any user ID.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with worldwide addresses. Is every country split up into states?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not sure of it. The advantage of this approach is that in **any** case, the information you are looking for (the country) is in that field.

Comment: Thinking about really small country like Vatican City State, I really doubt that all countries in the world are splitted up into states.

Comment: How would the Javascript API get current country? When I look at the [documentation for location](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), I only see it offer a name string and integer id.

Comment: 1st: your new question is a different argument from the first one, you had problem in retrieving a field using graph API, I suggested you a particular use of facebook API (FQL query on user table) and now you are asking something outside FQL, using user graph API directly, and with a specific SDK (Javascript)

Comment: 2nd: removing the "best answer" flag and asking a new question in comment is kinda like a blackmail

Comment: 3rd: put the flag back, ask the **new** question in a **new** topic (specifying that your are not allowed to use FQL like I suggested here) and I'll be glad to help you again, otherwise you'll not receive anymore help from me

Comment: (#12) fql is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher

Answer (score 3):

If you want more information you could use the latitude and longitude from https://graph.facebook.com/104022926303756 and feed them into a reverse geocoder.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=37.4293,-122.138&sensor=false

The Google API gives **a lot** of information, but it can be quite useful.
The country code may be a better idenfifier than the country name for example.
There's also the possibility to select output language. Adding **&lang=sv** gives you "Kalifornien" as the name of the state instead of "California".

Answer (score 0):

It comes inside the signed request when they hit your app. It comes even when they still didn't approve your app.