# How to get a Facebook user's current location using Graph API in JavaScript SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

This question was answered at [this link on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574979/how-to-get-a-facebook-users-current-country) by [thermz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/954680/thermz) using FQL. But I am trying to find a way to query the location information using the JavaScript Graph API (`FB.api`). Thermz's answer there returns a nice json object of the form:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "current_location": {
        "city": "Turin", 
        "state": "Piemonte", 
        "country": "Italy", 
        "zip": "", 
        "id": 115351801811432, 
        "name": "Turin, Italy"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can I get the same or similar structure through JavaScript SDK Graph API? Thanks.

Comment: Looking for the same thing :/

Comment: User location resource on Graph API is not the same thing that current_location on FQL old method..  the current location was a Geographic Info , but the user location on Graph API is just a field STRING filled by auto complete method =P   , it is not precise !   sometimes without country information..  Looking for the same thing too !

Answer (score -2):

You can use same as PHP Facebook SDK:

**// PHP**

```
$user_location = $facebook->api('/me?fields=location');
```

**// Java Script**

```
FB.api('/me?fields=location', function(response) {
     console.log(response);
   });
```